# Populating the column of table using Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am having a table layout in html with particular labels and styles . I need to update my table using particular elements 'id' of each row/element and fill up the data by using **ajax** . Needs solution/suggestion .

```
    <table border="0" style="margin-left:2%; margin-top:2%; ">
            <tr>
            <td align="left">Serial Number</td><td id="serialno"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>MaterialDesign</td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>TypeCode</td><td></td>
            </tr>
   </table>
```

How i can get data using ajax and put into "serialno" . As i had tried ajax which creates table dyanamically but not get help to put data if it is pre designed .

Comment: A bit more context and some code might help you get a proper solution

Comment: please show us your code.. what have you done till now... or else i am pretty sure.. u 'll be getting down votes.. and most probably the question will be closed... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `$("table #id").text("Your text");`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i am gonna give you two answers, but i personally like the first one .

**The first Solution :**

Lots of plugins are available to do tasks like this. My personal favourite is : **[jTable](http://www.jtable.org/)**

**"jTable is a jQuery plugin that is used to create AJAX based CRUD tables without coding HTML or Javascript."**

**The Second solution :**

Let's say we have a table structure like this :

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter">             
    <thead>> 
        <tr> 
            <th>first name</th> 
            <th>last name</th> 
            <th>age</th> 
            <th>total</th> 
            <th>discount</th> 
            <th>date</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>peter</td> 
            <td>parker</td> 
            <td>28</td> 
            <td>$9.99</td> 
            <td>20%</td> 
            <td>jul 6, 2006 8:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>john</td> 
            <td>hood</td> 
            <td>33</td> 
            <td>$19.99</td> 
            <td>25%</td> 
            <td>dec 10, 2002 5:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>clark</td> 
            <td>kent</td> 
            <td>18</td> 
            <td>$15.89</td> 
            <td>44%</td> 
            <td>jan 12, 2003 11:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>bruce</td> 
            <td>almighty</td> 
            <td>45</td> 
            <td>$153.19</td> 
            <td>44%</td> 
            <td>jan 18, 2001 9:12 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>bruce</td> 
            <td>evans</td> 
            <td>22</td> 
            <td>$13.19</td> 
            <td>11%</td> 
            <td>jan 18, 2007 9:12 am</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table><a href="#" id="ajax-append">append new table data</a><br><br>
```

Now we can do this to get the data as we want it :

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter(); 
    $("#ajax-append").click(function() { 
         $.get("assets/ajax-content.html", function(html) { 
             // append the "ajax'd" data to the table body 
             $("table tbody").append(html); 
            // let the plugin know that we made a update 
            $("table").trigger("update"); 
            // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column 
            var sorting = [[2,1],[0,0]]; 
            // sort on the first column 
            $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
        }); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

This is a table sorter application that i have applied a few times , but still the jTable plugin is the best solution to do such a job .